# What are the forums for internet startup founders?

Tags: webapp-rec, forums

What are the forums for internet startup founders?
(I hope if I remove the word best it is not argumentative anymore? Please do not close this question unless you add an answer here)

Comment: "Help me find an app that does X" is still a shopping question and not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Hacker News: http://news.ycombinator.com is one.

Answer (score 3):

Try the StackExchange [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) site, or [TheFunded](http://www.thefunded.com/) (registration and clearance required).

Answer (score 0):

StartUps are a particular subject strenth on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) too it seems.